# MySQL table not updated on exetcuting LOAD DATA LOCAL statement using Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am attempting to execute a MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL statement using Python. Below is the statement in MySQL which works as expected, i.e. data in file.csv is populated in MyTable.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/user/Downloads/file.csv' 
INTO TABLE MyDB.MyTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

When attempting to replicate this with the below I do not receive any errors but the table is not populated.

```
sql_statement = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/user/Downloads/file.csv'
INTO TABLE MyDB.MyTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"""

cursor.execute(sql_statement, multi=True)
connection.commit()
```

Anybody notice where I may be going wrong?

Comment: Do you call `commit()` on the connection?

Comment: I added 'connection.commit()' after the execute and again no error but no table update